# How many more transactions per second will be possible with SegWit?

Tags: segregated-witness, scalability, block-size-increase, transaction-capacity

1. On a percentage basis compared to the current theoretical limit how many more transactions per second will be possible after SegWit?
2. Will the answer to number 1 scale linearly with block size increases in the future?

Please exclude the impact of lightning or thunder networks for the purposes of my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Best estimates](https://bitcoincore.org/en/2016/01/26/segwit-benefits/) on effective blocksize with SegWit are 1.6-2.0 MB.

Current transactions/second possible are around 3 tx/s. Given that the effective increase is 1.6 - 2.0x, the transactions/second are also the same multiple giving us somewhere around 5-6 tx/s.

The second question is harder to answer. There's a reason I wrote "effective blocksize" since segwit transaction sizes are different. However a straight blocksize increase on top of segwit indeed would be linear.